# Debugging assembler in VS 2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, assembly, visual-studio-2017

I've created empty c/c++ project in VS2017 with options:

- unchecked create directory for solution
- added libcmt.lib as additional option in command line (Properties -> Linker -> Command Line)
- Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem (Properties -> Linker -> System)
- Generate Debug Information (/DEBUG) in Generate Debug Info (Properties -> Linker -> Debugging)
- Debugger type: Mixed
- masm in Build Customization files

The rest are default. Although those options debugger dosn't hit breakpoints in asm file. What could be the issue?

Comment: you need  look for command line for *asm* file - are `/Zd` options exist ?

Comment: There is  /Zi option . I have added it(/Zd) but it wouldn't help

Comment: usual command line for masm need be `ml[64] /c /Cp /Zd filename.asm` - exactly `Zd` generate debug info for asm file. and of course in linker must be `/DEBUG` option, but you say that it exist

Comment: ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\%(FileName).obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta - these options are in Microsoft Macro Assembler command line. I have added additionaly /Cp and /Zd option but still nothing

Comment: you can direct search in *pdb* file - are full path to your *asm* file is exist here and are *pdb* file name in *exe* exist - if yes - the debug info generated correct and lok like something wrong with vs debugger. you can try debug your code in another debugger, which support source  debugging, *windbg* for example - are in it you can debug asm code on source level ?

Comment: Start debugging with Debug > Step Into.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules and locate your executable file in the list.  Look at the Symbol Status column to ensure the PDB is loaded.  If not then right-click and select Symbol Load Information, it tells you where it looked for the PDB.

Comment: Set Debug -> Options -> Enable adress-level debugging.